# Table parallel rowspans

Tags: html, html-table

**Update**

More solved examples **[here](https://codepen.io/mikele/pen/MOeWgE)**

--

I am having a hard time with rowspans in a table.

I want to achieve the followings.

[image]

Explanation is always appreciated.

Also, any other example you think it would help understand, please share.

Here's the snippet:

```html
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings for holiday!</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br><br><br>

<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings for holiday!</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following code it's easy to understand if you get to know about how the flow of table works

```html
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings for holiday!</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">January</td>
    <td rowspan="2">$100</td>
    <td>$50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br><br><br>

<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings for holiday!</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td rowspan="2">$50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thx. From these 2 solved examples I got how rowflow works.